# Is it possible to use vue-flash-message without installing Node.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to figure out is it possible to use [vue-flash-message](https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message) in a WordPress plugin without NPM or Node.js installed. My idea was to try to include the [script](https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message/blob/master/dist/vue-flash-message.min.js)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('/vue-comp/vue-flash-message/vue-flash-message.min.js', __FILE__);?>"></script>
```

and then do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueFlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message';
    Vue.use(VueFlashMessage);

    new Vue({
        // root node
        el: "#vue_contact_form_app",
        // the instance state
        data: function () {
            return {}
        }
```

and then do

```
this.flash(...);
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `import` statement which is used to load an external module into the current scope.

In the simplest level of understanding, these lines:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message';
```

can only be valid in the NodeJS environment. More than that, it also need a transplier like Babel to make those lines of code valid in NodeJS environment, because NodeJS's module management system currently only support `require()` method for loading external modules.

If you don't know what Babel is, this is a short description of it:

> Babel is a JavaScript compiler. Babel is a toolchain that is mainly used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript in current and older browsers or environments.

Then, the answer for your question:

> is it possible to use vue-flash-message in a WordPress plugin without NPM or Node.js installed

That is impossible.